# How to create array of object in JSON from data in SQL table by SQL query?

Tags: sql, json, database, ssms

I want to create array of object in json from sql query. So I created the SQL query as follows :

```
Select society as Society,
   (select Name as [ID.FirstName],schoolName as [School.School_Name] from Details for json path ) as Students
   
From Details
For json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

I wanted my JSON result should look like this:

```
{ "Society":"England",
 "Students":[
    {
      "Id":{
        "FirstName":"Harry"
      }
    },
    {
      "School":{
         "School_Name":"St.Stephan School"
       }
    }
  ]
 }
```

I am getting the different output but I know this is not the generic way to write the code.

```
{ "Society":"England",
  "Students":[
    {
      "Id":{
        "FirstName":"Harry"
      },
      "School":{
         "School_Name":"St.Stephan School"
       }
    }
  ]
 }
```

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Your query will not run as JSON names can't be the same within the same object. Please correct

Comment: @Serg Yes it is wrong, So if i want to add another object in my array, so how should i proceed in this case?

Comment: @Serg I changed. Can you please me help me now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work...

```
select [Name] as [ID.FirstName], schoolName as [School.School_Name] 
from Details 
for json path, root('Students')
```

I looked at the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for the "for json" command.  I don't think you need to split up your select fields the way you did.  Also, I added the brackets around "Name" because memory is telling me that it's a reserved word, and you can force it to treat it as a field name with the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if my desired output should be like { "Society":"Engliand",
"Students":[
    {
      "Id":{
        "FirstName":"Harry"
      }
    },
    {
      "School":{
         "School_Name":"St.Stephan School"
       }
    }
  ]
 }

Comment: Then I think root may not work

Comment: And root and without array wrapper can't be used together

Comment: Okay... I think dropping the command to skip the array wrapper could give you what you were looking for.  I don't have a way to test it.